# How to iterate through a directory_iterator in parallel?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

`std::filesystem::directory_iterator` is a `LegacyInputIterator` and apparently it can't be used in a parallel `std::for_each`

I can iterate through the `directory_iterator`, get the items, place them in a vector and use that vector for parallel iteration.

Can the above step be omitted? Is there a way to iterate through a `directory_iterator` in parallel like this:

```cpp
std::for_each(
    std::execution::par_unseq, // This is ignored currently
    std::filesystem::begin(dir_it),
    std::filesystem::end(dir_it),
    func
);
```

Comment: `std::foreach()` can only be used with a parallel execution policy if the iterators meet requirements of `LegacyForwardIterator`.   `LegacyInputIterator` does not qualify - so cannot be used in multi-pass or parallel algorithms.   Practically, that is because traversing a directory happens in one direction  on most real-world systems (i.e. iterate from first to last entry, but not iterate back and forth through directory entries) so directory iterators can be readily implemented to meet requirements of `LegacyInputIterator`  but not requirements of  `LegacyForwardIterator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) is an input iterator, which means it generates values during the traversal. Furthermore, multiple traversals over the same directory may produce different sequences of values (both in terms of order and values themselves), which means the traversal is not restartable.

For parallel algorithms this means that the sequence cannot be partitioned, the iteration must happen sequentially, in one thread. The only opportunity to parallelize the processing is to offload `func` execution to separate thread(s), which may or may not be efficient. Filesystem iteration is expensive, and may be even more expensive than the processing in `func`. In this case you may observe `func` to be called sequentially, when each call manages to complete before the iterator increment does.

Standard library implementation is [permitted](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel.exec#7) to ignore the execution policy argument and execute the algorithm serially. For example, the implementation may simply not bother parallelizing the function calls if the input sequence cannot be partitioned.